# Conversion from `zoo` to `xts` creates lots of NAs in the index

Tags: r, time-series, xts, zoo

I have a rather strange problem that is probably best described by an example of an R session. I've tried to make this reproducible, as asked for in the comments below.

```
meto <- structure(c(30, 25, 25, 25, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20), index = structure(c(12796, 
            12796.0416666667, 12796.0833333333, 12796.125, 12796.1666666667, 
            12796.2083333333, 12796.25, 12796.2916666667, 12796.3333333333, 
            12796.375), format = structure(c("d/m/y", "h:m:s"), .Names = c("dates", 
            "times")), origin = structure(c(1, 1, 1970), .Names = c("month", 
            "day", "year")), class = c("chron", "dates", "times")), class = "zoo")
```

The example dataset looks like:

```
> meto
(13/01/05 00:00:00) (13/01/05 01:00:00) (13/01/05 02:00:00) (13/01/05 03:00:00) (13/01/05 04:00:00) 
                 30                  25                  25                  25                  20 
(13/01/05 05:00:00) (13/01/05 06:00:00) (13/01/05 07:00:00) (13/01/05 08:00:00) (13/01/05 09:00:00) 
                 20                  20                  20                  20                  20 
> str(meto)
‘zoo’ series from (13/01/05 00:00:00) to (13/01/05 09:00:00)
  Data: num [1:10] 30 25 25 25 20 20 20 20 20 20
  Index: Classes 'chron', 'dates', 'times'  atomic [1:10] 12796 12796 12796 12796 12796 ...
  ..- attr(*, "format")= Named chr [1:2] "d/m/y" "h:m:s"
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "dates" "times"
  ..- attr(*, "origin")= Named num [1:3] 1 1 1970
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "month" "day" "year"
```

When we convert to XTS:

```
m <- as.xts(meto)
```

Which leads to the following output:

```
> str(m)
An ‘xts’ object from NA to NA containing:
  Data: num [1:10, 1] 30 25 25 25 20 20 20 20 20 20
  Indexed by objects of class: [chron,dates,times] TZ: 
  xts Attributes:  
 NULL
> summary(m)
     Index          m       
 Min.   :NA   Min.   :20.0  
 1st Qu.:NA   1st Qu.:20.0  
 Median :NA   Median :20.0  
 Mean   :NA   Mean   :22.5  
 3rd Qu.:NA   3rd Qu.:25.0  
 Max.   :NA   Max.   :30.0  
 NA's   :10                 
Warning message:
In data.row.names(row.names, rowsi, i) :
  some row.names duplicated: 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 --> row.names NOT used
```

As you can see, the zoo time series has a lot of data in it, indexed by chron objects. However, when I convert it to a `xts` time series using `as.xts`, it looks ok to begin with...but the `str` command shows NAs and comparing the summary of `meto` to `m` shows that over 36,000 NAs have been created in the index!

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening, or what I can do to solve it?

Comment: Without the actual dataset, it is harder to provide an answer. Try to create a  mockup dataset that reproduces this problem. You can add a few lines of code to create the mockup dataset in your post so we can run the code. In addition, coming up with a reproducible example sometimes already solves the problem :).

Comment: Thanks Paul. Is there a way to easily dump part of a dataset to a string that can easily be read back in from the command line? The only way I can think of providing data (other than manually creating the data) would be to provide the CSV files for download.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra: I've made it reproducible (I think...)

Comment: I edited the post a bit to make it easier to copy into an R session. In addition I separated the code from the example R output.

Comment: Thanks @PaulHiemstra. Now we've got the post sorted out I hope someone can answer!

Comment: interesting, I can reproduce the problem but I don't know where is the problem.

Comment: Note that you can simply assign the results of `dput` to a variable.  Thus I have removed the redundant `meto <- dget(textConnection(...` bit of code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your index is of class `chron`.  I know very little about `chron`, but AFAIK it is generally preferred to use POSIX datetime objects in R, i.e. `POSIXct` or `POSIXlt`.

Somewhere in the conversion from `zoo` to `xts` the `chron` class information gets destroyed.

Converting your index to class `POSIXct` resolves the issue.

```
index(meto) <- as.POSIXct(index(meto)) 
as.xts(meto)

                    [,1]
2005-01-13 00:00:00   30
2005-01-13 01:00:00   25
2005-01-13 01:59:59   25
2005-01-13 03:00:00   25
2005-01-13 04:00:00   20
2005-01-13 04:59:59   20
2005-01-13 06:00:00   20
2005-01-13 07:00:00   20
2005-01-13 07:59:59   20
2005-01-13 09:00:00   20
```

---

For more information about working with R dates and time classes, see `?DateTimeClasses`, `?POSIXct` or `?strptime` - which all leads to the same help page.

---

**EDIT**

If `xts` is supposed to handle `chron` objects when importing from `zoo`, you have probably found a bug in the function `xts::xts`.

The problem occurs in this line:

```
if (inherits(order.by, "dates")) 
    index <- as.numeric(as.POSIXct(strptime(as.character(order.by), 
        "(%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S)")))
```

But notice that the format of your `chron` object is `("d/m/y", "h:m:s")` - I know this from your `str(meto)`.  Look carefully - there is a misalignment between day and month.

This may well be a locale issue.  I believe the package author lives in the USA, where the standard format is m/d/y, but in many other places the standard format is d/m/y.

So, somehow in the conversion between zoo and xts the conversion code should adjust for the locale of the user.

I suggest you contact the package author with this information.

Comment: Usually I work with POSIXct for datetimes. Chron is a bit of a mystery for me as well. I have heard lubridate is quite good for this kind of stuff.

Comment: Thanks Andrie - that solves it for now. However, I'm still interested as to why `chron` indices don't seem to work - the XTS documentation suggests that they do (and I have other XTS objects with chron indices working fine)

Comment: Lubridate is useful, and gives you some very convenient wrappers around POSIXct.

Comment: @robintw I think you have found a bug.  I have tried to explain the nature of this bug in my EDIT.  May I suggest you contact the package author.

Comment: @Andrie - thank you very much, I will get in touch with him/her now.

Comment: When there are no time zones then chron is preferred to POSIXct since it eliminates the possibility of subtle time-zone related bugs which POSIXct can introduce. See R News 4/1.

Comment: Thanks @JoshuaUlrich, I'd actually emailed Jeff before that, but thanks.